# Directory not found when integrating a template in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to integrate a template in my laravel project.

Error Message:

```
GET http://localhost/safeAgency.com/public/files/bower_components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I want to access the file in this way:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('local_agent/../files/bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

#### Explanation! about my folder structure and the above link:

I have a folder named `local_agent` in the `public` directory of my project. In this local_agent directory folder, I have two folders named `files` and `dashboard` . `HTML` file exists under the dashboard folder. But inside the `files` folder `bower_components` folder exists then `bootstrap` then blah blah. Another thing is required to mention here: The `"bootstrap.min.css"` file is located in the folder named `files` means one level up from the current folder. That's why I have used `../` before the file. Hope you understand.

Comment: No need `../` use direct link, 
like :  `local_agent/files/bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Sir, I have tried in this way but still, the error remains the same as it was.

Comment: It gives you 404, means your file path is not correct. Please place a directory structure image for better understanding of the asset files.

Comment: Whats about `href="/local_agent/files/bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: Thank you the problem has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this file just like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('local_agent/files/bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```